# preg_replace doesn't accept unicode

Tags: php, regex, string

I'm trying to maintain only valid characters and Hebrew Unicode characters from a string using `preg_replace`.

I'm getting an error on this string:

```
$PLAINText1 = preg_replace('/[^(\x20-\x7F),(\x05D0-\x05F2)]*/','', $PLAINText);
```

The error is:

> Compilation failed: range out of order in character class at offset 25 in....

I already know the error is in this phrase only: `(\x05D0-\x05F2)`

I read many post about this issue here and didn't find a solution. One relevant post suggested adding } to the Unicode, so on this string:

```
$PLAINText1 = preg_replace('/[^(\x20-\x7F),(\x{05D0}-\x{05F2})]*/','', $PLAINText);
```

I'm getting the a different error:

> character value in `\x{...}` sequence is too large at offset 22 ...

Please help.

Answer (score 3):

`\x` only accepts two hex digits, so your range is translating to "ENQ character, D, anything between 0 and ENQ (this is the error), F or 2"

Try adding the Unicode modifier `u` at the end of your regex, and use `\x{05D0}` to explicity tell it how many characters to use as the hex number.

Comment: i tried this, it returns nothing, no text and no error: $PLAINText1 = preg_replace('/[^(\x20-\x7F),(\x{05D0}-\x{05F2})]*/u','', $PLAINText);

Comment: also tried: $PLAINText1 = preg_replace('/[^(\x{0020}-\x{007F}),(\x{05D0}-\x{05F2})]*/u','', $PLAINText); still nothing...

Answer (score 1):

As an aside notice, you can have valid Hebrew characters with: `\p{Hebrew}` and avoid them with `\P{Hebrew}`

Answer (score 0):

you should change the file to utf 8 encoding for example: notepad++ go to encoding -> encode to UTF-8 and it shudold work: `preg_replace('/[^\p{Hebrew}a-zA-Z0-9_ %[].()&-]/u','', $q)` I also added "u" as a modifier.

Answer (score 0):

Below will replace any unicode chars except alphanumaric, Hebrew and underscore.

```
$foo = preg_replace('/[^\w\x{05D0}-\x{05F2}]+/u', '', $foo);
```

And below will replace any unicode chars except ASCII chars from 20 to 127 and Hebrew.

```
$foo = preg_replace('/[^\x{20}-\x{7F}\x{05D0}-\x{05F2}]+/u', '', $foo);
```